# API call undefined

Tags: javascript, api, axios

Hello guys im trying to use the API from HAPPi using axios, i get the data in the console but when i try to get the values i want, i get allways undefined (i also tried with vanilla and ajax but i get the same thing).
im newbie so i can't find out what im doing wrong.

```
axios .get("https://api.happi.dev/v1/music/artists?apikey=here_goes_the_api_key&page=1")
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);

        const artistName = response.data.result.artist;
        const artistCover = response.data.result.cover;
        const artistInfo = response.data.result.api_artist;
        const artistAlbums = response.data.result.api_albums;

        document.getElementsByClassName('artistName').innerText = artistName;
        document.getElementsByClassName('artistCover').innerHtml = artistCover;
        document.getElementsByClassName('artistInfo').innerHtml = artistInfo;
        document.getElementsByClassName('artistAlbums').innerHtml = artistAlbums;

    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: you need an api key to make a request. Get an api key from the api's website and insert it after `?apikey` query paramter in the request url

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a NodeList, not a single element.

Comment: you are right i forgot that, i changed to id but i still get undefined

Answer (score 0):

you need to register at https://happi.dev/ using your email address and you will get an api-key which needs to be inserted in the api call url

https://api.happi.dev/v1/music/artists?apikey=your_key_here&page=1
like this, hopefully this will fix the issue you are facing and if you still face issue try using double quotes when calling below method. 
`document.getElementsByClassName("artistName").innerText = artistName;`

Comment: i already have the key, but i did not exposed here, i just wrote here without it, so that is not the problem, because i get all the data

Comment: did you try using double quotes around class name?

Comment: this is my html:

<div class="artist">
                    <h2 class="artistName"></h2>
                    <img class="artistCover" src="" alt="artist cover">
                    <p>
                        <a href="" class="artistInfo"></a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="" class="artistAlbums"></a>
                    </p>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the problem, i wasn't indexing the object like this:

```
const artistName = response.data.result[0].artist;
const artistCover = response.data.result[0].cover;
const artistInfo = response.data.result[0].api_artist;
const artistAlbums = response.data.result[0].api_albums;
```

thanks for all the help